# How to create "utils.py" file using Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I hope you're doing well.

I'm new to Flask, and I'm trying to build my first website using this framework and SQLite as a database to play with. I'm also using the App Factory pattern.

I was thinking about creating a utils file where to put my repeated code in, and one of the very simple functions I need to include in such file deals with the database.

It is as follows:

**utils.py**

```
def get_categories():
    tuple_list = []
    categories = Category.query.all()
    for category in categories:
        new_tuple = (category.id, category.name)
        tuple_list.append(new_tuple)
    return tuple_list
```

As you can see, very simple function, it just gets categories from the database and returns them in a format I want to have, a list of tuples.

Now, the problem is that when I run the server with **python run.py**, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
```

I know why I'm getting this, an app context is needed to perfom operations with the database. But, I cannot import my "app" object because it gives me a "circular import error".

If I do this:

```
def get_categories():
    tuple_list = []
    with app.app_context():
    categories = Category.query.all()
    for category in categories:
        new_tuple = (category.id, category.name)
        tuple_list.append(new_tuple)
return tuple_list
```

I get this:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'posts' from partially initialized module 'soyciro.posts.routes' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\Ciro\Documents\projects\python\soyciro\soyciro\posts\routes.py)
```

I have a ****init**.py** file in my app directory, which is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from soyciro.config import Config

from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager

db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    from soyciro.main.routes import main
    from soyciro.posts.routes import posts
    from soyciro.work.routes import work
    from soyciro.users.routes import users
    from soyciro.categories.routes import categories
    app.register_blueprint(main)
    app.register_blueprint(posts)
    app.register_blueprint(work)
    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(categories)

    return app
```

I also have a **run.py** file in the root directory of the app which has the following:

```
from myapp import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If you need more information, please let me know.

Thanks in advance,
Ciro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Importing **app** would of course give you circular import, instead of using importing app directly you can create flask context by using current_app from a flask.

```python
from flask import current_app as app


def get_categories():
    tuple_list = []
    with app.app_context():
        categories = Category.query.all()
        for category in categories:
            new_tuple = (category.id, category.name)
            tuple_list.append(new_tuple)
    return tuple_list
```